# cs file not getting generated for SpecFlow feature file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, testing, specflow

I'm working on SpecFlow tests in Visual Studio 2019. The designer file (.cs) doesn't get generated when the feature file is added.

Works on other machines with similar configuration and nuget packages.

The designer file should be generated automatically.

Comment: Are you using Specflow 2 or 3? If you are using Specflow 2 then you have to downgrade your visual studio extension??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably happening, because the generation of the code-behind file on saving is not enabled.

In the latest update of the VS Extension of SpecFlow we changed the default to false. The reason for it was, that it is a legacy function and you should switch to MSBuild Generation of the code-behind files.

Documentation for it: https://specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild/

To enable the feature again, you have to go to the options:

[image: SpecFlow options screen]

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the developer of SpecFlow.

Comment: Yeah that works. Thanks. I figured it out earlier that it must be something to do with the options disabled.